# How to back from Component in react redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

i have a Car page, includes one edit and add components, it's working fine when i dispatch with button now i am trying to back from the component using button, i tried history.goBack but its going to home page

**Home page** `localhost:8080/`

**Issue page** `localhost:8080/car/5c7a29418c57f7069f382491`

above page, i have `<CarAdd>` and `<CarEdit>` includes, dispatch using below button

```
 <button  type="button"  onClick={() => 
     this.props.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_NEW_CAR'})}>
                   Add Car
 </button>
```

then Add car shows, i used editing: true and enable this component, component have car add form, then how can i BACK using button

```
   <button onClick={history.goBack}>Back</button>
```

// going to **Home page** **not localhost:8080/car/:id**

---

```
  <Link to="/car/5c7a29418c57f7069f382491">Back</Link>
```

// not working

Comment: Have you got react-router browserHistory in your application?

Comment: yes, `import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();`