# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting this error on my Addpage:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

I am trying to go back from a component like in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048541/how-to-back-from-component-in-react-redux).

How do I go back from my Addpage?

```
const onClick = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'AMENITIES_BACK', id: roomsManager.items.parentId })
}

const AmenitiesAdd = ({ handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting }) => {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Field label="amenities" name="newAmenities" component={InputText} validate={validateNotEmpty} type="text" />
            <Field label="description" name="newDescription" component={InputText} validate={validateNotEmpty} type="text" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>Back</button>
        </form>    
    );
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'AmenitiesAdd'
})(AmenitiesAdd)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Import withRouter

   ```
   import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
   ```
2. Export your component as:

   ```
   export withRouter(nameofcomponent)
   ```
3. Example, on button click, call goBack:

   ```
   <button onClick={this.props.history.goBack}>Back</button>
   ```

Tested on react-router-dom v4.3